# How to use BB Webworks childBrowser in a Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, twitter-oauth, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, window.open

I am running into an issue with doing oAuth with Twitter/Facebook using childBrowser on Phonegap and BB10. I have this working perfectly on iOS/Android.

Per the Phonegap 2.7.0 docs, `window.open()` and `window.close()` are the only methods that are supported on BB10.

Since the oAuth methods rely on looking detecting URL changes in the child browser window to parse and access the oauth tokens, I need a way to be able to attach event listeners to the childBrowser window. Unfortunately, this is also not supported by Phonegap 2.7 on BB10.

So, I found this soultion here: https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/Twitter-OAuth-1, but unfortunatley this does not work as the childBrowser for Phonegap takes over the call to `window.open()`.

Has anyone run into this issue? I am not sure what to do here.

Is it possible to disable/remove the `InAppBrowser` in Phonegap 2.7 so that `window.open()` relies on the built in childbrowser in BB10?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, maybe it helps https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/childBrowser

By the way I have found working with WebWorks SDK far much easier and faster for Blackberry

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote the BlackBerry ChildBrowser API sample above, you should be able to get a handle on the childWindow just fine.

Have you tried running the sample app on it's own, and checking console.log?

Comment: I have run the example app and see a similar issue. When I try to use your Twitter-Oauth-1 script and call `var currentURL = childWindow.window.location.href;`, childWindow.window is undefined on my end. Thus the script fails and is unable to get the location of the url even the Twitter oauth process completes to the end and is returned back to the callback url.